# HTACCESS: How to REDIRECT ALL urls contains "a word" to only one other URL?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect, cpu-word

Lets say we have the urls (which contains "***vvvvv***") inside. For example:

- http://www.example.com/***vvvvv***
- http://www.example.com/***vvvvv***/
- http://www.example.com/***vvvvv***/somepage
- http://www.example.com/*some-dir*/***vvvvv***.php?arg=whatever

All those above (containing "***vvvvv***" word inside) will be going to:

- ***"http://www.google.com"*** .. only. Neatly. (To a Domain ONLY. Without any carryings/ trailing)

How to make it in `.htaccess` please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteRule vvvvv http://www.google.com? [L,R=301]
```

That should do it I think. The `?` at the end of the destination URL means "don't send any query string".

Answer (score 0):

This rule works. I've tried it with a different rule. Not sure if the ? will work, but if you use a direct URL as the final destination URL, it will function properly.