# bulk redirect when url contains a set of words

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Ițm trying to create a bulk redirect for some content I'm deleting from a wordpress site. So, the actual links that would be deleted look like this (notice the **https**):
https://www.domainname.com/some-word-identical-phrase-12-monthname-year/year/month/day/

And I need to redirect them all a page.

I've tried this rule following some other instructions on stackoverflow:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} horoscopul-zilei-de
RewriteRule .* /pagename [R=301]
```

Obviously it didn't work.. 
Help is really appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Why didn't that work?

Comment: I have no idea.. that's why I was asking for help here.

Comment: I've rechecked and the rule redirects to the index.php instead of the page from the rule.

Comment: Use example in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17654747/htaccess-how-to-redirect-all-urls-contains-a-word-to-only-one-other-url/

It did the trick for me.